# Can I travel outside Schengen and return if I have a D visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, long-stay-visas

This question may be the duplicate of another, but I didn't find one specifically for Italy. I have a D visa (for staying more than 90 days in Italy), but I haven't yet gotten a residence permit.

Can I travel to Croatia through Slovenia and return to Italy the same way through Slovenia? Some say that I should wait until I get the residence permit before leaving Italy and/or the EU. The problem here is that Croatia is not a Schengen country.

Comment: Is your D visa valid for multiple entries?

Comment: Will your D visa expire before you return to Italy?